# how to use countif with array excel 2016?

Tags: arrays, excel, countif

In an excel spreadsheet I have multiple sites with 2 rows of data for each site (A, B). There are 25 observations (columns 1 - 5) for each site. I would like to count the number of cases for each site where A + B > 0.
For example,

```
Site1 A 0 0 1 2 0
Site1 B 1 0 1 0 0
```

the count would be 3 (that is A+B >0 for 3 cases in site 1). I could add a third line for each site to get the sum and then count the number of cells > 0, but I am not interested in adding an additional line for each site. I have not found an array formula that works for this situation.

Comment: what do you mean by a site? also can you add a screenshot of your data? having the data described in a single paragraph doesn't really help

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld kindly edited the example data.  This is a solution I came up with: {=SUM(IF((c2:g2>0)+(c3:g3>0),1,0))}  Ron Rosenfeld’s answer is more elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(--((C1:G1+C2:G2)>0))
```

This is an array formula.

In older versions of Excel, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((C1:G1+C2:G2)>0))
```

Or you can enter the original as an **array formula**

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That does what I needed.